# Is it possible to gain access to Raspberry Pi (headless) after disabling SSH

Tags: raspbian

I want to disable all services such as: SSH, VNC, etc., so it is impossible to gain access to my Raspberry Pi (It will be running a program using the internet, possibly on public networks.) But, in the future I would like to be able to gain access to it again without a monitor and keyboard, mouse etc. Is this possible?

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B running Raspbian Jessie Lite (2016-11-25)

Also, I would rather not have to buy a console cable.   What I have available now is an ethernet cable and the ability to read and write to my SD card.

Comment: Could you please specify the model of the Pi to be used?

Comment: Those cables are really not expensive - it's typically just a USB to serial (UART at logic levels) cable. But extending on Steve's thought to keep SSH up and running and harden it: from the question I take it that the device will be connected to a public network anyways and will run a service that exposes itself to this network. Question is what makes you think this is in any way more safe than providing a properly set up sshd?

Comment: In terms of not expensive banggood has them for less than $3 dollars http://www.banggood.com/search/usb-to-ttl-cable.html and under $5 ordered from their US warehouse.

Comment: @Ghanima Even if the cable is cheap there is always the drive/wait to get one so I rather not. If I must I will though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have physical access to the Pi you could use a console cable connected to the Pi and a laptop. Adafruit has a very good [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview) on using a console cable with the Raspberry Pi, and sells the [cable](https://www.adafruit.com/products/954) as well.

If you won't have physical access to the Pi you could leave SSH enabled, but secure it. You can read how to do this on our [blog](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/148032481829/ssh-security-and-usability-part-1) (note: there are still at least two additional posts in the series covering the crypto and port knocking).

Comment: Don't forget to `enable_uart=1` at `/boot/config.txt` for the Pi3.

Comment: @Ghanima It is covered in the tutorial I linked to.